# Update Duplicate Data when insert data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I've search and try to solve the issue but failed to grab solution sorry for taking your time.
I am inserting a set of data in laravel with the query builder to insert multiple data at a time.

```
DB::table('table')->insert(
array(
    array(
        'col1' => 'data1',
        'col2' => 'data1'
    ),
    array(
        'col1' => 'data2', 
        'col2' => 'data2'
    ),
)
);
```

Is there any way to check if exist the `col1,col2` value in table if exist then update otherwise insert. I wanted to get return `true` or `false` from the query result if all data successfully update or inserted. I wanted to solve it with laravel query builder.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Laravel query builder does not support this.
You could do a raw MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

But that is very messy and MySQL specific.

Instead i would suggest you use the Eloquent ORM:

```
// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: first or create doesn't taking much keys and values I've try it

Comment: Yes you need to loop your data, because it will try to get or create one model at a time.